# Python and the zipfile module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-zipfile

According to Python documentation:

> ZipFile.extract(member[, path[, pwd]])
>   **Extract a member from the archive to the current working directory**; member must be its full name or a ZipInfo object). Its
>   file information is extracted as accurately as possible. **path
>   specifies a different directory to extract to**. member can be a
>   filename or a ZipInfo object. pwd is the password used for encrypted
>   files.

I have large number of zipped files that each contain 1000 archived files in them. Using the function above I can extract only the files that I need from each zipped archive:

```
def getAIDlist(aidlist_to_keep,ifile,folderName):

    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(ifile) #
    aidlist=archive.namelist() # gets the names of all files in the zipped archive

    print "AIDs to keep",aidlist_to_keep

    print  "Number of AIDs in the zipped archive ",len(aidlist)

    path='/2015/MyCODE/'+folderName

    for j in aidlist_to_keep:
        for k in aidlist:
            if j in k:
                try:
                    archive.extract(k,path)
                except:
                    print "Could Not Extract file ",(j)
                    pass

    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    getAIDlist(['9593','9458','9389'],"0009001_0010000.zip","TestingFolder")
```

Ideally I want the extracted files to be stored into `TestingFolder`, but instead they are stored in a newly created folder `0009001_0010000.zip` inside `TestingFolder`.

How can I direct the extracted files directly into `TestingFolder` but without creating a new folder `0009001_0010000.zip`?

Comment: i tried your code.. For me the files are directly extracted to TestingFolder. No new folder is created

Comment: Really? Which version of Python are you using? I am running Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64) . I tried it multiple times but the folder 0009001_0010000.zip is always created inside the TestingFolder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use `extract()`, you can use [`ZipFile.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) and copy the file to a filename of your own choosing; use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to efficiently copy the data across:

```
import shutil

archive = zipfile.ZipFile(ifile)
path = os.path.join('/2015/MyCODE', folderName)

for name in aidlist_to_keep:
    try:
        archivefile = archive.open(name)
    except KeyError:
        # no such file in the archive
        continue
    with open(os.path.join(path, name), 'wb') as targetfile:
        shutil.copyfileobj(archivefile, targetfile)
```