# How to unzip files with Python without reading them all into memory?

Tags: python, zip, unzip

I am currently using `zipfile` to unzip files with Python. However it seems all the data is loaded into memory, which causes some problems with my application.

Is it possible to unzip a zip with Python and not write all its content into the memory?

Comment: Does it have to be in Python? Python ain't the world's best unzip programme. You could use subprocess and get a fast unzip application and unzip it passing the result back and forth?

Comment: Prefarably in Python. But if there is a good alternative I could use with subprocess, I would use that too.

Comment: This has been answered before, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1763408/1130446

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224916/python-and-the-zipfile-module/28225407#28225407) for example?