# How to decompress zip files across a Windows folder in Python

Tags: python, windows, zip, compression

I have a large folder having 900+ sub-folders, each of which has another folder inside it which in turn has a zipped file.
Its like -
-MyFolder
-----MySubfolder
---------MySubSubfolder
-------------MyFile.zip
How can I decompress all the zipped files in their respective folder OR in a separate folder elsewhere in Windows using Python?

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28225407/4014959) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28766502/4014959), both by Martijn Pieters.

Comment: thanks a lot! but how do I recursively unzip hundreds of files in different locations? Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [os.path.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk) to recurse through a directory. Also see [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). The `os.path` module has many useful functions for working with files and directories, like `.isfile(path)`, `.isdir(path)` and `.splitext(path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
import zipfile,os;
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        for member in zf.infolist():
            extract_allowed = True;
            path = dest_dir;
            words = member.filename.split('/');
            for word in words:
                if (word == '..'):
                    extract_allowed = False;
                    break;
            if (extract_allowed == True):
                zf.extract(member, dest_dir);
def unzipFiles(dest_dir):
    for file in os.listdir(dest_dir):
        if (os.path.isdir(dest_dir + '/' + file)):
            return unzipFiles(dest_dir + '/' + file);
        if file.endswith(".zip"):
            print 'Found file: "' + file + '" in "' + dest_dir + '" - extracting';
            unzip(dest_dir + '/' + file, dest_dir + '/');
unzipFiles('./MyFolder');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you tell what          "      if (word == '..')       "       does?

Comment: @RakeshTripathi this is check in case if there should be any relative paths in zipped archive to avoid extreacting files outside from given path (dest_dir). In your case its probably not an issue.